# java 1.8 - gradle can't find main class

Tags: java, class, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to run a gradle build with gradlew. My folder structure looks like this:

```
src
└── main
    └── java
        └── hello
            └── Greeting.java
```

This is my build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

mainClassName = 'hello.Greeting'
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']


jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

I can run ./gradlew build successfully, but ./gradlew run exits with:

```
 Task :run
 Error: Could not find or load main class hello.Greeting
```

Greeting.java is just a simple class with a main method:

```
package main.java.hello;


public class Greeting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("greet");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your main class (Greeting.java) source code as well?

Comment: i doubt your java build path. Jre failed to recognize your main class. ?

Comment: @adarshr I updated my question to show main class.

Answer (score 1):

Your package is incorrect. Change it to `package hello;` and it will work.

`src/main/java` is the source folder and it is not part of the package.

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Do you mean change package main.java.hello to just package hello ? Because if i do that then this happens when i run in IDE: Error: Could not find or load main class main.java.hello.Greeting

Comment: By defining sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src'] you set the source path to the specified folder. This means your Package in the Hello class must be "package main.hello.java". The real solution to your problem ist: remove the sourceSet definition from you build file. Generate the eclipse project files again by calling "gradle cleanEclipse eclipse" and set the package in your class to "package hello;" as recommended by adarshr. Also you have to match the package name for mainClassName. In your example this has to be "mainClassName=main.hello.java.Greeting"

Answer (score 0):

Remove main from package definition in java file or 
Remove your inconsistent SourceSet definition or change it to

```
sourceSets {
   main {
     java {
       exclude 'some/unwanted/package/**'
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my directory structure, but this isn't necessary if the following rules are applied.

```
src
└── hello
    └── main
        └── java
            └── Greeting.java
```

Need to specify correct sourceSet structure

```
sourceSets {
    hello{
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/hello/main/java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the path has to be identical to the source set structure.

Define main class name:

Has to refer to one of the source sets

```
mainClassName='hello.main.java.Greeting'
```

But can also be something like:

```
mainClassName='hello.main.java.x.y.Greeting'
```

, if we wish to add some folders to the package.

Comment: This is all wrong. You just need to fix the package name as I explained in my answer.